# Ignore Blank Cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I need some help with an Excel Formula.

I have three columns with values going from 0 to 4 (They describe the results of single tests). In the fourth column I put the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(A3=0;B3=0;C3=0);0;(IF(OR(A3=1;B3=1;C3=1);1;SE(AND(A3>1;B3>1;C3>1);2))))
```

Basically if any value in `A`, `B`, or `C` is =0, the fourth column needs to be 0. If none is 0, but at least one is =1, the fourth column needs to be 1. If the values are all between 2 and 4, the 4th column should be 2.

My problem is that some of the values will be blank because one of the tests wasn't done and I need the formula to ignore them and analyze only the cells where there are numbers. How do I do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use `countblank(A3:C3)-countif(A3:C3;0)` to count the true number of zeros

Comment: ignore last comment! You can use `countif(A3:C3;0)` to count the true number of zeros and then use an if statement like =IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2;0)>0;1;IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,1);2;3))

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=IF(COUNT(A3:C3); MIN(A3:C3; 2); "")
```

If no numbers exist, then a zero-length string is the result and the cell looks blank. One or two truly blank cells will be ignored in the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The *MIN()* function ignores blanks, so consider:

```
=IF(MIN(A3:C3)=0,0,IF(MIN(A3:C3)=1,1,2))
```